# dotnet build intermittently exits with Segmentation fault (core dumped) or 139 on linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using dotnet core sdk 2.1.403 and building projects on linux. Intermittently the build fails with either Segmentation fault or with 139

The build itself doesn't start, as soon as the command "dotnet build" is issued it comes out with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" or with 139.

The platform that i am using is
RedHatEnterpriseServer 7.3
Linux2x86_64

Please can someone provide some insights into this.

The content of the project file is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>$(BROOT)/bin</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>Simple</AssemblyName>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>$(OutputPath)</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="x">
      <HintPath>$(BROOT)/bin/x.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
   <Exec Command="rmdir /S /Q obj" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
   <Exec Command="rm -r obj" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: This sounds like something that should be reported as a bug to .NET Core. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` indicates a bug/crash originating in unmanaged code. Can you enable core dumps and include as much of that in the bug report too?

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind: does this problem still occur on the latest version of RHEL 7? It's at 7.7, I think.

Comment: @OmairMajid: Thanks for the response. Haven't tried with the latest version of RHEL. Probably will give a try

Comment: Have the sysadmin check the /var/log/messages file for an OOM (out-of-memory) KILL.  There may be a memory shortage and the kernel kills the process trying to free memory to continue working.